# convert byte array into syscall.InotifyEvent struct in Golang

Tags: go, inotify

I'm playing around with the inotify functionality in golang's syscall library. I'm able to setup the inotify functionality with `InotifyInit`, add a file to watch with `InotifyAddWatch` and detect file changes with the `Read` function. The problem that I'm having is that the `Read` function only reads into a byte array containing info about the inotify events. I'd like to convert/cast that byte array into an `InotifyEvent` structure so that I can access information about the inotify events properly

Below is what I have so far:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    buff := make([]byte, 64)
    inotefd, err := syscall.InotifyInit()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    _, err = syscall.InotifyAddWatch(inotefd, "/home/me/foo", syscall.IN_MODIFY)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for {
        n, err := syscall.Read(inotefd, buff)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        if n < 0 {
            fmt.Println("Read Error")
            return
        }

        fmt.Printf("Buffer: %v\n", buff)
        //can't cast []buff into InotifyEvent struct
        fmt.Printf("Cookie: %v\n", buff[0:4])
        fmt.Printf("Len: %v\n", buff[4:8])
        fmt.Printf("Mask: %v\n", buff[8:12])
        fmt.Printf("Name: %v\n", buff[12:13])
        fmt.Printf("Wd: %v\n", buff[13:17])
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `unsafe` package for that:

```
    info := *((*syscall.InotifyEvent)(unsafe.Pointer(&buff[0])))
```